# generalizing ajax call into function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to attempt to generalize my ajax calls into a function as follows. I have not done this before and am not sure sure if I'm doing it correctly.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    var reg_no=$("#reg_no").val();
    reg_no=reg_no.trim();
    if(reg_no!==""){
        //populate fields
        data={reg_no:reg_no,func:"getSupplierDetails"};
        success_function="updateFormFields";
        ajax_call(data,success_function);  
     }
});

function ajax_call(data,success_function){
    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:"../control/supplier-c.php",
        dataType:"json",
        data:data,
        success:function(data){
            success_function(data);  //variable function works??
        }

    });
}

function updateFormFields(data){
    //some code here to handle data array   
}
</script>
```

What I'm trying to do here is avoid rewriting the whole ajax code by passing the data array and the function to be executed on success. What I'm not sure is the use of variable functions as i have done.

A note to be made is that the whole thing works for an ajax call if updateFormFields() code was moved into the success handler in the ajax call and the ajax_call() was not defined as a seperate function but implemented right after  the comment "populate fields". I just have no experience in trying it this way and I need to know if this is possible or not.

Thank You

Comment: if your question is about the success: callback, then that will work ... though, you can do `success:success_function` instead

Comment: i see, I just wanted to find a way to avoid retyping the same line of code in the ajax_call() multiple times. I have a few more ajax calls in my website

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Javascript, functions are first class objects, meaning you can pass them around as parameters.

```
function json_post(url, data, success_function, error_function) {
    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:url,
        dataType:"json",
        data:data
    }).then(success_function, error_function);
}
```

Then you can call it as

```
json_post("../control/supplier-c.php", { data: "data" }, function (res) {
    console.log('Ajax req successful');
    console.log(res);
}, function (res) {
    console.log('Error in ajax req');
    console.log(res);
});
```

In your case, you can do:

```
ajax_call(data, updateFormFields);
```

and it should work as expected.

Comment: can you confirm that my way of implementation is wrong, as in erroneous? not the deprecated use of success callback. Because my implementation doesn't work.

Comment: Yes, your implementation is wrong. Check jquery ajax documentation here .. http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/#jQuery-ajax-settings for `success` , it is mentioned that `success` must be a Function, not a String.

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to wrap the success function, you can just apply apply it directly.

```
function ajax_call(data, success_function) {
    $.ajax({
        ...
        success: success_function
    });
}
```

An even better idea is to avoid the legacy `success` and `error` callbacks and instead return the jQuery promise. You can use standard promise methods `.then()` and `.

```
function ajax_call(data) {
    return $.ajax({
        ...
    });
}

ajax_call()
    .then(function(data) {
        // this runs if it succeeds
    })
    .fail(function(err) {
        // this runs if it failed
    });
```

Promises have a huge benefit to being chain-able, making the code flatter, avoiding the nest of "christmas tree callbacks".

Comment: But in function ajax_call(data, success_function), variable success_function is a string. Will it be executed as a function when written as you said?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend checking `success_function` as well as `failure_function` to handle server response (XHR) errors also.

```js
function success_function(){
  //code to handle success callback
}

function error_function(){
  //code to handle failure callback
}

function ajax_call(data, success_function, error_function) {

  if (typeof success_function === 'function' && typeof error_function === 'function') {
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "../control/supplier-c.php",
      dataType: "json",
      data: data,
    }).then(success_function).fail(error_function);
  }
}
```